# Адрес страницы по типу '?'

Tags: php

Есть страница адрес которой, допустим `vk.com/id` в ней имеется разметка.
Используя адрес `vk.com/id?1` - подгружаются данные из базы по ID 1.
Как сделать адрес без **`?`** (`vk.com/id1`) но с той же "механикой"?

Comment: Используйте htaccess.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, можно ссылку или название такой "механики", даже не знаю как загуглить.. :с

Comment: полный путь по которому к вам обратились находится в `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` от туда его достаете и выделяете нужную числовую часть. А что бы при любых url попадало к вам на скрипт смотрите .htaccess на предмет "rewrite". Или прямо при rewrite выделяете числовую часть и предаете скрипту в обычном параметре, как например тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/5669174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как реализовал я (спасибо другим форумам и @Mike за инфу)

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)/?$ id.php?id=$1 [L]
# В моём случае, если id имеет число, считается как id.php?id= (если правильно понял)
```

Проверка в **`id.php`**

```
$url = str_replace('/id','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //
if($url == '') { // если $url (ссылка) пустая
  header('location:404.html'); // отправляем на страницу 404
} else {
  // Ваш код, у меня тут "связывание" с базой
}
```

---

Тапками не кидаться, в PHP вообще ноль.
Если не согласны с вариантов - отвечайте, проверю, вознагражу (+rep)